Translation map on set
How do I read/interpret this statement?
Let X denote the collection of all functions from the set $ {1,...,p} $ to the set ${1,...,n}$, where $p$ is a prime, and $n$ is any positive integer.

Observe that the set X has some symmetry:  There is a translation map T : X → X, given by
the formula : $(Tf)(i) $ =
$ f(i−1) $ if $i>1$ ; else $(Tf)(i) =
f(p) $ if $i = 1$.


Write examples. If $p<n$ and $f(x)=x$, then $(Tf)(x)=\begin{cases}x-1,&\text{ for }x>1\p,&\text{ for }x=1\end{cases}$

What is the symmetry here? I don't see it.

Translation is a symmetry. You can reverse it, you can compose it with further translations.
